# Omitting the Inverse Mills Ratio and corresponding coefficient from a model?

Tags: tobit-regression, heckman

I have a question with regard to the inverse mills ratio as part of my type II Tobit model (Heckman model).

The residuals of my Probit and OLS are not significantly correlated (r = 0,000666; p-value = 0,977). This results in a very small coefficient value for $\mu$. However, when I include $\mu \lambda$ in my model it causes insane multicollinearity which is strange as the highest VIF score without this variable is 1,72.

Could I justify omitting $\mu \lambda$ from my model by explaining that the insignificance of the covariance indicates that there is no selection bias?